# What fedex paper to use for toner transfer

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, printed

I am very new to creating PCBs and I am planning to make my first one in the upcoming weeks.  I noticed that all the instructions and tutorials called for using a laser printer which I do not have easy access to.  I decided that I would print my design using FedEx office.  I am unsure what paper would be the best to use.  I was wondering if "Laser" paper or "Gloss Text" would likely work for the purpose of transferring toner to a pcb.

Comment: Will they let you supply your own paper?

Comment: Also, make sure they aren't using a Brother printer. They use a different toner formulation that doesn't melt twice.

Comment: Maybe but I doubt it is easy to do online

Comment: Ignacio: I've heard that, but I have a Brother printer laser printer at home and it's worked fine for my toner transfer PCBs; that said, I'm using a hot roller laminator, not an iron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use magazine paper (thank you, old Nat Geo subscription). The key is that there needs to be some kind of emulsion on the page that can separate from the paper. Some people recommend using photo paper, though I haven't tried it.

The issue I'd see is it would be more difficult to get another print quickly if you screw something up (wrong orientation, missed a component, etc.)

From the options provided on the FedEx Office site, the only one that looks like it might work is Gloss Text.